# Group items in an array by date

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have an array which contains dates and bin colors.  Some bins are collected on the same date so i want to group these dates then have an array of bin colors.

The data structure i'm looking to achieve is:

```
"items": [
        "item": {
            "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
            "bins": [{
                "bin": "Blue"
            }, {
                "bin": "Grey"
            }]
        },
        ...
]
```

Data array:

```
var dateList = [{
        "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bin": "Blue"
    }, {
        "date": "2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bin": "Blue"
    }, {
        "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bin": "Green"
    }, {
        "date": "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bin": "Green"
    }, {
        "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bin": "Grey"
    }, {
        "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bin": "Grey"
    }]
```

Here's the code i have so far, it's almost there but instead of creating items.item it creates items[date], but i can't figure out the last part:

```
    var items = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < dateList.length; i++) {

        if(!items[dateList[i].date]) {

            items[dateList[i].date] = {};
            items[dateList[i].date].date = dateList[i].date;
            items[dateList[i].date].bins = [];
            items[dateList[i].date].bins.push( { "bin": dateList[i].bin });

        } else {
            items[dateList[i].date].bins.push( { "bin": dateList[i].bin }); 
        }
    }
```

This results in items[date]

```
"items": {
    "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Blue"
        }, {
            "bin": "Grey"
        }]
    },
    "2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "date": "2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Blue"
        }]
    },
    "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Green"
        }, {
            "bin": "Grey"
        }]
    },
    "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "date": "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Green"
        }]
    }
}
```

I would prefer it if i could structure it like items.item

```
"items": [
    "item": {
        "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Blue"
        }, {
            "bin": "Grey"
        }]
    },
    "item": {
        "date": "2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Blue"
        }]
    },
    "item": {
        "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Green"
        }, {
            "bin": "Grey"
        }]
    },
    "item": {
        "date": "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Green"
        }]
    }
]
```

thanks

Comment: Your requirement is impossible to fullfill: you require an object `items` to have multiple properties with the same `item` name. The property names MUST be unique.

Comment: And after your edit you have an `items` array of (?) key/value pairs? Try using a JSON-aware editor and format correctly your JSON structure.

Comment: You seem to have some misunderstanding as to how objects work in JavaScript. Each member of the object needs to be unique, so they cannot all have the name item.

Comment: @A.Chiesa my mistake, i've updated requirement for an array of items.

Comment: Is the result "items" which you prefer Object or Array?

Comment: @scott - even after update its not valid array...

Comment: Came here to say what A.Chiesa said. Because you are storing these on an object the property names must be unique. With that said you may be able to mutate it to be an array.

Comment: Just remove all 'item' keys. And that will make sense. ;)

Comment: I would personally suggest items to be like this: `[ { "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z", "bins": [ "Blue", "Grey" ] }, ... ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get array of objects, you can use it as the following code. Please note that the order when using `Object.keys()` is not guaranteed.

I put there two methods, one is just simple array, the second one is array with `item` keyword as the wrapper for each object in array.

```js
const items = {
    "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Blue"
        }, {
            "bin": "Grey"
        }]
    },
    "2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "date": "2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Blue"
        }]
    },
    "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Green"
        }, {
            "bin": "Grey"
        }]
    },
    "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "date": "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000Z",
        "bins": [{
            "bin": "Green"
        }]
    }
}

const array = Object.keys(items).map(key => items[key]);
const arrayWithItems = Object.keys(items).map(key => ({item: items[key]}));
console.log(array);
console.log('!!!! -------- !!!!!');
console.log(arrayWithItems);
```

Comment: The source data is different from the requirement in the question, AFAICT.

Comment: @A.Chiesa - the requirement in a question does not have any valid array...

Comment: @A.Chiesa - but ok, I put both possibilities there

Comment: order by date:  array.sort(function(a, b){return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date); });

Answer (score 1):

My take on this:

```js
var dateList = [{
    "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bin": "Blue"
}, {
    "date": "2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bin": "Blue"
}, {
    "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bin": "Green"
}, {
    "date": "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bin": "Green"
}, {
    "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bin": "Grey"
}, {
    "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bin": "Grey"
}]

let dictionary = {};
for(let i = 0; i < dateList.length; i++) {
  const item = dateList[i];
  if (!dictionary[item.date]) dictionary[item.date] = { date: item.date, bins: [] };
  dictionary[item.date].bins.push(item.bin);
}

const result = Object.values(dictionary);

// if you need to have distinct values in bins:
result.forEach(obj => obj.bins = new Array(...new Set(obj.bins)));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the result you are expecting is invalid. The javascript array will not accept the key values. The array is the list of items or objects. Below is the output you can get.

```
//Output
[
  {
    "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bins": [
      {
        "bin": "Blue"
      },
      {
        "bin": "Grey"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-11-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bins": [
      {
        "bin": "Blue"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bins": [
      {
        "bin": "Green"
      },
      {
        "bin": "Grey"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-11-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bins": [
      {
        "bin": "Green"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Below is the javascript code to derive the output.

```
//Code
var noDuplicates = [];
var lookupObject  = {};
for(var i in dateList) {
    lookupObject[dateList[i]['date']] = dateList[i];
}

//Create the array with unique dates
for(i in lookupObject) {
    noDuplicates.push(lookupObject[i].date);
}

var results=[]
//Iterate and filter the original array with same date value
for(i in noDuplicates) {
    var groupedArray = dateList.filter(obj => {
      return obj.date === noDuplicates[i]
    })
    //Form the bins array for the output
    var bins = groupedArray.map(obj => {
      return {
        'bin': obj.bin
      }
    })
    //Construct the output object
    results.push({
      'date': groupedArray[0].date,
      'bins': bins
    })
}
```

Yes. It is a straight forward solution with little bit of manipulation for getting the unique values first. Hope it resolves your problem.